# I can't deploy mysql to LXC:0 with juju

Tags: mysql, juju

I used "juju deploy --to lxc:0 mysql" to deploy mysql.
But ,the container start failed.--"error: container failed to start"
so,I used dmesg to look error message:

```
[1318582.474759] init: maas-txlongpoll main process (40475) killed by USR2 signal
[1318582.474789] init: maas-txlongpoll main process ended, respawning
[1378229.942871] type=1400 audit(1411959544.645:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default" pid=23647 comm="apparmor_parser"
[1378229.943327] type=1400 audit(1411959544.645:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-mounting" pid=23647 comm="apparmor_parser"
[1378229.943799] type=1400 audit(1411959544.645:19): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-nesting" pid=23647 comm="apparmor_parser"
[1378230.015537] type=1400 audit(1411959544.717:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/lxc-start" pid=23657 comm="apparmor_parser"
[1378230.409478] Bridge firewalling registered
[1378230.627744] type=1400 audit(1411959545.329:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/lxc-start" pid=23744 comm="apparmor_parser"
[1378230.643423] type=1400 audit(1411959545.345:22): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default" pid=23749 comm="apparmor_parser"
[1378230.643438] type=1400 audit(1411959545.345:23): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-mounting" pid=23749 comm="apparmor_parser"
[1378230.643448] type=1400 audit(1411959545.345:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-nesting" pid=23749 comm="apparmor_parser"
[1378230.644196] type=1400 audit(1411959545.349:25): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-mounting" pid=23749 comm="apparmor_parser"
[1378230.644207] type=1400 audit(1411959545.349:26): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-nesting" pid=23749 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

I stuck,who could help me..Thank you so much.

I used `juju deploy --to lxc:1 mysql` to deploy mysql. It didn't work. So, I checked the log of machine 1:

```
[ 8256.358378] br0: port 2(vethPGUSW7) entered forwarding state 
[ 8256.359027] br0: port 2(vethPGUSW7) entered disabled state 
[ 8256.407420] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethPGUSW7: link becomes ready 
[ 8256.407693] br0: port 2(vethPGUSW7) entered forwarding state 
[ 8256.407706] br0: port 2(vethPGUSW7) entered forwarding state 
[ 8256.417367] device vethPGUSW7 left promiscuous mode 
[ 8256.417402] br0: port 2(vethPGUSW7) entered disabled state
```

Comment: Can you share the logs from `juju debug-log`? If there are any logs from LXC on that machine too then those too would help.